# Can I join two Entities and bind the result to a DataGridView in a way that the DataGridView edits can be applied to the database?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview, datatable, join

I'm new to The Entity Framework. I need to show the result of two joined tables in a DataGridView and update the database when the user edited the data.

Without EF I usually fill a dataset and assign it to the DataSource property of a datatable and manually write the UpdateCommand. But don't know how to do this with EF.

This is how I'm implementing it right now:

```
Dim Query2 = From Product In db.Products
                 Join User In db.Users
                     On User.Id Equals Product.Owner.Id
                 Select New With {
                     Product.Id,
                     Product.Title,
                     User.UserName
                    }

DataGridView2.DataSource = Query2.ToList
```

Comment: You would have to give the "combined" type properties that passed-through to the properties of the original separate entities so you can't do it with an anonymous type unless you were to loop through the list of anonymous objects and update the original entities before saving.

Comment: you'll have to have properties of your POCO entities bound to the view, and the properties of the navigation properties as well. Note that this will only work for updates, not inserts and deletes, and that this violates the SOLID principle.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Then I have to define an additional class for joined data, right? But what do you mean about passing through properties?

Comment: If you want to be able to do what you said then yes, you need to define your own class.  A "pass-through" property is one that, rather than storing a value in a private field of the current object, simply passes data through to and from another internal object.  For instance, you might create a user control with a `TextBox` as a child control and a `TextBoxText` property.  That property would simply get and set the `Text` property `TextBox`, thus passing data through rather than storing it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the type of class I suggested:

```
Public Class UserProduct

    Private user As User
    Private product As Product

    Public Property UserName As String
        Get
            Return user.UserName
        End Get
        Set
            user.UserName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ProductId As Integer
        Get
            Return product.Id
        End Get
        Set
            product.Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ProductTitle As String
        Get
            Return product.Title
        End Get
        Set
            product.Title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(user As User, product As Product)
        Me.user = user
        Me.product = product
    End Sub

End Class
```

As you can see, the properties simply pass data through to the corresponding properties of the inner objects rather than storing it directly.

Your LINQ query would then become:

```
Select New UserProduct(user, product)
```